# cassandra highscore

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, data-modeling

If I want to have only the queries for:

```
1. Username, Xp, OtherUserData
2. User with the N-th highest Xp
```

How would I have to do the data structure and query.

For 1. I would have a structure similar to:
{ Username: { Xp, OtherUserData}}

Would I just have to do a query for 2. over all users, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking (is Xp the user's score?), but here's a guess:

To store user data, create a row per user, keyed on their username (assuming this is unique and fixed) and then a column for each item:

```
username ->  Xp      other    ...
             value   value    ...
```

To maintain a high-score table, use a single row (probably in a different column-family), with all users (or those above a certain threshold), with column names that are the scores, and specify a numeric (LongType) Comparator so that the columns are sorted by score:

```
highscores -> 1000      1001      99999999   ...
              user123   user345   user789    ...
```

You can then retrieve the highest N scores by querying for the last or first N columns in this sorted row. You could remove low scores from this row if it gets too big.

**Update**: As you point out, multiple users could have the same score. A quick-and-dirty solution would be to make the value a list of users:

```
highscores -> 1000      
              "user123, user567, user899"
```

This is tolerable if you are unlikely to get large number of users with the same score, though awkward since you need to read, update, and write the list.

You could use supercolumns, though these are not usually recommended.

Otherwise you could probably use [composite column keys](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) so that you can distinguish users, but maintain columns sorted by score.

Comment: How can I handle 2 Users with te same score?

Answer (score 1):

Using only one row for classification could be quite dangerous as each row seats on only one instance of Cassandra. Thus all players in your system would write to that ONE key - on one machine - with the risk of overloading a node in your cluster. That could potentially make all the cluster fail due to a weird chain reaction of nodes trying to shoulder the loads of a downed node while it was trying to recover (we had that happen on our production machines, because of a bug where an hard coded test key would receive all the writes that were meant to be in separate rows for everyone).

A solution would be to bucket your users by their scores:

- 0- > 1000 = bucketA
- 1001 -> 5000 = bucketB
- 5001 -> 15000 = bucketC 
  and so on.

I would advise to make the lower level buckets smaller.

And write your column with the column names as a composite:
CompositeType(LongType, UTF8Type)

so for example if you use UUID as player ids and longs as scores we would have:

- 500089845:f7bc41d8-c1c6-489c-bb2c-f86fccc7681c
- 4100085589:2ae91e9f-1512-4ef8-8441-9f48e21fb11b

you can do it with concatenated strings but you'd have to write all the leading zeros so that the UTF8 comparator would but all the scores in the right order.

1. 000000500089845:f7bc41d8-c1c6-489c-bb2c-f86fccc7681c
2. 000004100085589:2ae91e9f-1512-4ef8-8441-9f48e21fb11b

without leading zeros would be

1. 000004100085589:2ae91e9f-1512-4ef8-8441-9f48e21fb11b
2. 000000500089845:f7bc41d8-c1c6-489c-bb2c-f86fccc7681c

This way you do not have to read to modify a vector, json, composite or super column of people having the same scores since every score is a separate column. You can put whatever info you want in the column so that you can get everything in one read (without having to fetch player info with another read, personally I'd do that with a json or a byte serialized object that contains everything I need).

To read: an inverted range query (highest first) on the rows you want will do the trick.

You can vary the flavours of your system by changing the nature of the buckets too, as long as you have enough rows to touch all the nodes, thus sharing the load across you token ring.

hope that was helpfull